# Jquery append set speed

Tags: jquery

HI I wrote the following short script and I want to set the "appearance" to slow. So that it basically fades in slowely and not just pops in. How do I do that? I want to keep append though.

```
     <script>
$( "#text" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span>Climate change: 'Monumental' deal to cut HFCs, fastest growing greenhouse gases</span>" ) );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
  }
);
 </script>
```

Comment: You probably want to use `.hide` and `show`. Look m up and see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fadeIn function on previously hidden `span`:

```
$("#text").hover(
  function() {
      $( this ).append( $( "<span>Climate change: 'Monumental' deal to cut HFCs, fastest growing greenhouse gases</span>" ).hide().fadeIn('slow'));
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
  }
);
```

### -DEMO-